# How to delete multiple checked records in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

I figured out how to display checkbox for each row.
The problem is that I can't find out how to write form_tag and submit tag in order to pass the checked rows parameter to messages_controller with using detele action.
and what to write in delete action.

Please help me out!

My view is

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>delete</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Read</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Sender</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
  </tr>


<% @messages.each do |m| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag '', m.id, false, class: 'delete_multiple_checkbox', name: "conversations[]" %>
    <td><%= m.last_message.id %></td>
    <td><%= 'unread' if m.is_unread?(current_user) %></td>
    <td><%= m.last_message.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= m.last_sender.username %></td>
    <td><%= m.subject %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and controller should be something like this( according to this here https://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging/blob/master/app/controllers/messaging/messages_controller.rb)

```
def trash
  conversation = Conversation.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if conversation
    current_user.trash(conversation)
    flash[:notice] = "Message sent to trash."
  else
    conversations = Conversation.find(params[:conversations])
    conversations.each { |c| current_user.trash(c) }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages sent to trash."
  end
  redirect_to messages_path(box: params[:current_box])
end
```

route.rb

```
Example::Application.routes.draw do



 root :to => "top#index" 
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

 get 'girls', :to => 'girls#index', :as => :user_root
 match '/girls/comment' => 'girls#comment', :via => :post
 get "girls/show"
 resources :girls
 resources :home

 devise_for :users do get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

 resources :girls do 
   collection do
     get 'tag'
   end
 end


  resources :contacts
  resources :user_profiles

  match 'messages/new/:username', :to => 'messages#new'



  get "messages/sent"
  get "messages/trash"
  get "messages/received"
  get "messages/show"
  get "messages/trash"
  match '/messages/deliver' => 'messages#deliver', :via => :post


end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the syntax listed below to fit your requirement:

```
Model.where(:id => [1,2,3,4,5]).destroy_all
```

or

```
Model.where(id: params[:id]).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is wrap the whole messages rendering block with a form_tag and add a submit_tag wherever you'd like. I assumed your controller is MessagesController under blank namespace and the action is trash. Note that if your controller is under messaging namespace you might want to change the :controller => :messages into :controller => 'messaging/messages'.

```
   <% form_tag :url => { :controller => :messages, :action => :trash}, :method => :delete do %>
      <% @messages.each do |m| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag '', m.id, false, class: 'delete_multiple_checkbox', name: "conversations[]" %>
          <td><%= m.last_message.id %></td>
          <td><%= 'unread' if m.is_unread?(current_user) %></td>
          <td><%= m.last_message.created_at %></td>
          <td><%= m.last_sender.username %></td>
          <td><%= m.subject %></td>
       </tr>
      <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag "Trash All Checked" %>
    <% end %>
```

I also assumed your routes.rb accepts a HTTP DELETE method for the specified route. You can check that with `rake route | grep messages` and verify the route is set. 
If it is not you will have to add it with:

```
resources :messages do
    collection do
         delete :trash
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I just copied and pasted it. but it now doesn't show any records that it used to be shown....:(

Comment: You mean it does not render any message tr?

Comment: indeed it renders everything but record rows somehow. :(

Comment: try    `<%= form_tag :url => { :controller => :messages, :action => :trash}, :method => :delete do %>` (note the = sign after the opening <% )

Comment: Yeah, now it renders:) thanks!! but if I mark some checkboxes, and hit delete submit button, it still says the error 'No route matches [POST] "/messages/received" '      Then the url on the address bar looks like this '/messages/received?method=delete&url%5Baction%5D=trash&url%5Bcontroller%5D=messages'  this is so weird.

Comment: `<%= form_tag { :controller => :messages, :action => :trash}, :method => :delete do %>` . Please paste here the rendered html form tag afterwards.

Comment: Now, it actually takes me to /messages/trash?method=delete this look right to me. but it still keeps saying error 'Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/messages/trash" ' I already added get "messages/trash" to my routes. So I cannot figure out why it says routing error.:(