# rails updating multiple rows in single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have a table with set of students, I want update attendance column to all the students with different values using single form which will save all the record.

note: i was able to save all the records individually.

here is my edit page

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>user_id</th>
      <th>Present days</th>
      <th>Total days</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

<% @attendancce.each do |userr| %>  
<tr>
<%= form_for(userr) do |f| %>

<td><%=userr.user.name %></td>
<td><%= userr.user_id %></td>
<td><%= f.number_field :present_days %></td>
<td><%= f.number_field :total_days %></td>

<td><%= f.submit %></td>

<% end %>

</tr>

<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "submit" %>


and below is my method for updating the records

 def update
    @attendancce = Attendance.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @attendance.update(attendance_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @attendance, notice: 'Attendance was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @attendance }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @attendance.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

please suggest how to achieve my target

Comment: why do you have 2 submit buttons?

Comment: second button is dummy, i kept it so that i can update all the records with single click

Comment: that way you will never achieve it. Try to adapt your code to this. 

This is a tutorial on how to delete all selected items. Which is pretty clear to what you want, except you want to update instead of delete.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377727/how-to-delete-multiple-checked-records-in-rails